# Mobius transform in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, mobius-function

I am accounting some problems in understanding Mobius transform in complex analysis. Let for example consider simply the triangle with vertices $0$, $1$, $i$ and the following transform $f(z)= z/(z+1)$. I cannot realize the shape of the image if the triangle so defined. How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Möbius functions send circles to circles, where lines are also considered circles that go through a point at infinity. So you need to realize that this particular function sends the point at infinity to $1$

Comment: And, just for fun: http://youtu.be/JX3VmDgiFnY